# How can I read request header from program.cs file in .netcore6 webapi

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, multi-tenant

I have tenant id in request header. I want to connect database string based on the tenant id , how can i achieve this? I am using .netcore6 webapi. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this requirement through Middleware. Here is the test result and sample.

[image]

[image]

**My Test files and picutres**

[image]

*Test Method in HomeController*

```
    public IActionResult GetConnectionStringByTenantID()
    {
        bool testResult = false;
        string msg = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            testResult = _dbcontext.Database.CanConnect();
            if (testResult)
            {
                msg = "connect sucessfully";
            }
            else
            {
                msg = "connect failed";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            msg = e.ToString();
            throw;
        }

        return Ok(msg);
    }
```

*TenantMiddleware.cs*

```
using WebApplication7.Models;

namespace WebApplication7
{
    public class TenantMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public TenantMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            // Read the tenant ID from the request header
            var tenantId = context.Request.Headers["Tenant-Id"].FirstOrDefault();

            // Get the connection string for the tenant
            var connectionString = GetConnectionStringForTenant(tenantId);

            // Create a Tenant object with the tenant ID and connection string
            var tenant = new Tenant
            {
                Id = tenantId,
                ConnectionString = connectionString
            };

            // Set the Tenant object in the context
            context.Items["Tenant"] = tenant;

            // Call the next middleware component in the pipeline
            await _next(context);
        }

        private string GetConnectionStringForTenant(string tenantId)
        {
            // Implement logic to get the connection string for the tenant
            // This can be from a configuration file or a database
            // For example, you can have a dictionary of tenant IDs and connection strings
            var connectionStrings = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "tenant1", "Data Source=...My real test connectionstring..." },
                { "tenant2", "Server=server2;Database=database2;User Id=user2;Password=password2;" }
            };
            if (tenantId == null || tenantId.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                tenantId = "tenant1";
            }
            // Return the connection string for the tenant ID
            if (connectionStrings.TryGetValue(tenantId, out var connectionString))
            {
                return connectionString;
            }

            // If the tenant ID is not found, throw an exception
            throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid tenant ID: {tenantId}");
        }
    }

}
```

*MyDbContext.cs*

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication7.Models;

namespace WebApplication7
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly Tenant _tenant = null!;
        public MyDbContext()
        {

        }
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
            : base(options)
        {
            _tenant = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["Tenant"] as Tenant;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_tenant.ConnectionString);

        }
    }

}
```

*Program.cs*

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApplication7
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMiddleware<TenantMiddleware>();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

*Tenant.cs*

```
namespace WebApplication7.Models
{
    public class Tenant
    {
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public string? ConnectionString { get; set; }
    }

}
```